# Statistics for a dragon that has become a monk

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, dragons

I want to create an NPC Silver Dragon that has learned the monk class (17 levels) while morphed into a human, how should I go about creating it's ability scores and all of it's other statistics, and should I keep the new ability scores even in it's dragon form?

> In a  new form, the dragon retains its alignment, hit points, Hit Dice, ability to speak, **proficiencies**, Legendary Resistance, lair actions, and **Intelligence**, **Wisdom**, and **Charisma scores**, as wellas this action. Its statistics and capabilities are otherwise replaced by those of the new form, **except any class features** or legendary actions of that form.

While the last highlights ruins the idea I still want to break the rules a bit and would love some help.

To clarify, I'm asking if when the monk form would get an ASI and would raise it's Wisdom or Dex, should that change in the dragon form as well.

Comment: Have you checked the DMG chapter on creating custom monsters?

Comment: Do you want it to have the Monk class features specifically? If so, why?

Comment: Related: [What is the CR calculation for an NPC with class levels?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76716/41726)

Comment: Will it only ever be in its human monk form, or will it sometimes be in its dragon form too?

Comment: @Bloodcinder Mostly human

Comment: In my opinion, as posed right now this question seems to be asking "homebrew this for me" which I do not think is compatible with our format. Therefore voting to close

Comment: @Sdjz It's more asking of when the monk form would take ASI and he raises his Wisdom by 2, should that change for the dragon form as well.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you are asking: "a dragon transforms into a human, gains 17 monk levels, including ASI, what happens to the ASI when it returns to the dragon form?". You are not asking us what stats it should have in human form? From the one answer (so far) this is probably unclear. This is starting to become a long comment chain and I'd rather discuss this in [chat] if you'd like.

Comment: I think the original question that I answered was clear, but this new revision is not. "How should I go about creating it's ability scores and all of it's other statistics"/"Statistics for a dragon that has become a monk" is not the same question as asking about a rules interaction between ASI's and monster ability scores. I'm going to leave my existing answer because I think it addresses the root of the problem, but you should revise your question to only ask for 1 thing. As it is, you're asking for at least 2 related but different things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Add the half-dragon template to a monk-like stat block.

The simplest way to fulfill your needs is to use existing content in the rule books to produce your creature rather than wracking your brain trying to homebrew it or asking the community to homebrew it for you. This avoids reinventing the wheel and limits the need for playtesting.

In the *Monster Manual* there is a template called the half-dragon (p. 180). It can be applied to a humanoid creature with dragon lineage. Various flavor text is given about how a creature might gain dragon lineage, such as by being the offspring of a polymorphed dragon or by undergoing a blood ritual, but there's nothing particularly "halfish" about the half-dragon template, so it can easily be used for any humanoid you want to have dragon features. The creature to which the template is applied gains a damage resistance and breath weapon from the dragon it's based on without requiring any fiddly changes to ability scores.

You could create a 17th level monk using the player character rules and add the half-dragon template to it, but that's a lot of time to spend, and there's no reason to use player character classes unless you plan to treat the NPC as a player character in the party, and even then only if the players themselves are controlling the NPC.

It would simplify creating and running the creature if you find an existing monk-like stat block in the published rules add the half-dragon template to that. Even then, you don't need a monk in order to create a monk-like creature. If you describe the NPC as a dragon who became a monk and narrate its actions in that fashion, then the player characters will see it as a dragon who became a monk. All you really need is a high CR stat block of a humanoid creature who is a martial fighter. The *Monster Manual* and other bestiaries you may have (such as *Volo's Guide to Monsters* and *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*) are good sources.

## The bigger picture: improve your design method.

Here's my point. Your question basically amounts to asking the community to create a homebrew monster for you, and when you start asking whether monk class Ability Score Increases should affect a monster stat block under nonexistent rules then you're asking other people to do your work and your rulings for you. That strategy won't get you very far.

The techniques I've described in this answer are intended to teach you how to easily create a creature yourself using existing rules and published content without resorting to homebrew or asking the community to adjudicate rules that don't exist for hypothetical scenarios. You might not like my particular suggestion involving the half-dragon template. That's okay. You know what you want your NPC to be like more than I do. Use the available tools to design something better.